# php and mysql selecting 5 rows from mysql

Tags: php, sql, mysql

i am tryng to select 5 mysql rows from the database and display them like $row[1] ect.... in php i am not sure how to do it an someone lead me down the right way please
Ok i hav looked a bit more

i wanted it to come out 1 - 5 and i wanted it to display the names

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table  ORDER BY id DESC") or die (mysql_error()); 
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
  $name = $row['name'];

  $arr = array("somearray" => array(1 => 5, 2 => 9, 3 => 42, 4 => 42, 5 => 42));
  echo $arr["somearray"][1];
  echo $arr["somearray"][2];
  echo $arr["somearray"][3];
  echo $arr["somearray"][4];
  echo $arr["somearray"][5];

  }
```

Comment: dont have any thats why i am asking for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the OP wants five ROWS, not COLUMNS. Here is the correct code, assuming you already have a mysql connection open:

```
$sql = 'SELECT *
    FROM table_name
    ORDER BY col_name
    LIMIT 5';

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {

    $row[] = $line;

}

// print (access individual rows: $row[0] ... $row[4])
var_dump($row);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to select 5 rows from MySQL you can do this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table
ORDER BY column
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

From php.net :
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '42'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // 42
echo $row[1]; // the email value
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using MySQL's `LIMIT` clause to limit your results to 5 rows. And use PHP's [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) (returns an associative array) instead of [mysql_fetch_row()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) (returns a numerically indexed array). Also, it's good practice to free the memory associated with the result using [mysql_free_result()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-free-result.php).

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5") or die (mysql_error()); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $name = $row['name'];
    echo $name;
}
mysql_free_result($result);
```